# Finding the existance of a vector within matrix within list within list

Tags: r, list, exists

I have tried to use R to find a vector within a matrix within list within list. I have tried if the vector 'ab' exists by using the following 'exists' code but none of them work. How can I make it work?

```
 aa <- list(x = matrix(1,2,3), y = 4, z = 3)
 colnames(aa$x) <- c('ab','bb','cb')
 aa 
 #$x
 #     ab bb cb
 #[1,]  1  1  1
 #[2,]  1  1  1
 #
 #$y
 #[1] 4
 #
 #$z
 #[1] 3

 exists('ab', where=aa)
 #[1] FALSE
 exists('ab', where=aa$x)
 # Error in exists("ab", where = aa$x) : invalid 'envir' argument
 exists('ab', where=colnames(aa$x))
 # Error in as.environment(where) : no item called "ab" on the search list
 colnames(aa$x)
 #[1] "ab" "bb" "cb"
```

Comment: `ab` is not a `vector`; it's just the name of a column of a `matrix` (which _isn't_ made of vectors, but _it's_ a vector, with `dim` and `dimnames` attributes). You can `"ab" %in% colnames(aa$x)` to check if the `matrix` contained as the `x` element of the `aa` list has a column named `ab`.

Comment: are you interested in finding the name 'ab' or the content of 'ab'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column names are part of either `matrix` or `data.frames`.  So, we loop over the `list` using `sapply`, get the column names (`colnames`), `unlist` and check whether 'ab' is among that `vector`

```
'ab' %in% unlist(sapply(aa, colnames)) 
#[1] TRUE
```

If we want to be more specific for a particular `list` element, we extract the element (`aa$x`), get the column names and check whether 'ab' is among them.

```
'ab' %in% colnames(aa$x)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or another option would be to loop through 'aa', and `if` the element is a `matrix`, extract the 'ab' column and check whether it is a `vector`, wrap the `sapply` with `any` to get a single `TRUE/FALSE` output.

```
any(sapply(aa, function(x) if(is.matrix(x)) is.vector(x[, 'ab']) else FALSE))
```